# How to use Raspberry Pi to stimulate IoT devices traffic

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I wonder how can I use Raspberry Pi to stimulate IoT devices traffics. 
There isn't a lot of resources on google so I'd post my question here.

What tools could I use?

Thanks ahead

Comment: You probably use it like any other computing device, once you define what your "IoT devices traffic" looks like and what protocol(s) it uses.

Comment: Do you use [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot-core)? More detailed information about "stimulate IoT devices traffics" is helpful.